# Hiding DIV with absolute positioning causes reflow

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm curious if it expected behavior to do reflow when hiding absolutely positioned element?

Consider example code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .float {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #E0E0E0;
                padding: 5;
                left: 100px;
                top: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function toggle() {
                var float = document.getElementById("float");
                var style = float.style;

                if (style.display == "none") {
                    style.display = "block";
                } else
                    style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle();">Click to toggle!</a>
        <div id="float" class="float" style="display:none">Floating div</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I check Timeline tab in Chrome Dev Tools I see the following:

[image: Dev Chrome Tool Timeline]

Line 23 corresponds to `style.display = "none";` and my expectation is that no reflow is required.

Am I wrong? Or did I misinterpret Timeline results? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: For no reflow I think you will need to look at [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) rather than [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 2):

There is a reflow. When you change the display of an element, the browser needs to perform layout operations. Maybe you're confusing the idea of a layout pass, with a layout pass that affects the whole document. In your case, I think the layout affects only the .float element. You can see it clicking in the layout bar. It'll tell you the scope of the layout.

Contrary to what it may seem, hiding an absolute positioned element can cause a reflow of the whole page. This can happen, for example, if the positioned element is higher or wider than the browser viewport. In this case, hiding it could cause the scrollbars to disappear, and, as a result, a reflow of the whole document.

Each browser has its own methods to determinate whehter a whole document reflow is needed or not, so what works in a browser may not work in another. You have a good article here: [Introducing layout boundaries](http://wilsonpage.co.uk/introducing-layout-boundaries/)

EDIT: As @xotic750 said, you can avoid the reflow setting visibility: hidden. This causes the browser to avoid painting, but to the layout engine, it'll be there. This way it won't be a reflow when you show/hide it. The downside? Every time there is a reflow for another reason, the contents of your invisible div will be part of the layout process. If the div's DOM tree is simple, maybe playing with visibility is better. But if the div contains lots of objects, specially tables, I think you should use display: none. It'll also depend, of course, on the time the div is supposed to be visible or hidden.

Comment: In the example I provided when I click Layout item the whole page is being highlightened, not DIV itself.

Comment: +1 Good answer. But I think you meant `display: none` instead of `display: hidden`

Comment: Igor, now I pay attention to it, your div is positioned at (100px, 100px). The only other element in the page is an a element, whose size if much less than that. When you hide your div, the dimensions of the documentElement change. Again, I recommend you to read the article I linked.

Comment: Thank you, I will read the article and ask more questions later :)